# Postgresql statement to represent rows duplicate in column way

Tags: sql, postgresql, code-duplication

My data looks like:

| Member_ID | Housing_ID | National_ID | Family_relation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3214565 | Head |
| 2 | 1 | 1234567 | Wife |
| 3 | 1 | 1223344 | Sun |
| 4 | 1 | 3224451 | Sun |
| 5 | 1 | 5432175 | Daughter |
| 1 | 2 | 1223344 | Head |
| 2 | 2 | 4321678 | Wife |
| 3 | 2 | 4356723 | Sun |
| 1 | 3 | 3214565 | Head |
| 2 | 3 | 1234557 | Brother |
| 1 | 4 | 7653432 | Head |
| 2 | 4 | 3224451 | Grand daughter |

as you can see, there is a dulication of National ID in different houses:

```
1- the member 3 of house 1 with National ID 1223344 (sun) is (head) of house 2, 
2- the member 4 of house 1 with National ID 3224451 (sun) is (Grand daughter) of house 4
```

I have to specify all duplicated scenarios in order to remove it, I identify the duplication by typing : `select National ID , count(*) from my table group by National ID having count(*)>1` and got this output:

| National ID | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1223344 | 2 |
| 3224451 | 2 |

I'm tiring to query the duplication so the out put looks like:

| National ID | Housing ID 1 | Relation | Housing ID 2 | Relation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1223344 | 1 | sun | 2 | Head |
| 3224451 | 1 | sun | 4 | Grand daughter |

Thanks

Comment: What is the meaning of this table? What is its (intended) Primary Key? [data model:] should/must there only be **one** 'head' per household? Should a person be only be part of **one** household? Can the 'head' of a household be female?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For National_ID with count(*) = 2, the following query should provide the expected result :

```
select National ID
     , array_agg(Housing_ID)[1] AS "Housing ID 1"
     , array_agg(Family_relation)[1] AS "Relation 1"
     , array_agg(Housing_ID)[2] AS "Housing ID 2"
     , array_agg(Family_relation)[2] AS "Relation 2"
  from my table 
 group by National_ID 
having count(*) = 2
```